# 301 Redirect only Posts not Pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am looking to redirect all the posts and not pages and custom post types from old domain to new domain. So all posts for instance
`http://www.example.com/post1` should go to `http://example1.com/post1`
`http://www.example.com/post1` should go to `http://example1.com/post1`

The pages i.e. `http://www.example.com/page1` should still be functional

I can find alot of answers on moving blog into sub directory along with moving all the links but not for moving just the posts and not the pages

**Edit**
There are over 1000 posts so I am looking for a dynamic way of doing this

Thank you for your help

Comment: You want to do manually?

Can you do so  <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/old-post") { ?> 
<?php
header("Status: 301");
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com.br/old-post");
exit;
?>

Comment: there are more than 1000 posts in the blog so the old blog example.com will be non functional retaining the pages , where as the new domain will have all the blog posts from old I have already moved domain just want to make sure the old urls are 301 redirected

Comment: I am happy to do the redirect with functions.php if required But I am not sure exactly how to do this

Comment: @QuebrandoCabeca there are alot of posts that needs to be moved

Comment: how to understand - the post is URL or page?

Comment: Have you tried this in .htacess RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST}! Newdomain.com $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Http://newdomain.com/$1 [L, R = 301]

Or see this link http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/

Comment: @splash58 I am using wordpress for my website

Comment: @QuebrandoCabeca this redirects all urls (all) from old to new domain I am looking to redirect only posts and not pages

Comment: @June, a see, you should understand post or page before wordpress started. I would write a php script with array of page names and redirect by it

Answer (score 1):

The hack I finally end up using was

1. Add ob_start to single.php as first line even before get_header()
2. Add following code in functions.php

change `example.com` with your site domain name

```
add_action('wp_head','redirectme');
function redirectme() {
    if ('post' === get_post_type()){
        wp_redirect( 'http://example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , 301 ); exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think this is possible with this URL schema. .htaccess (or the Apache behind it) doesn´t know if `post1` is a post or page. How shall it then redirect on this base?

If you would change the URL structure for pages alone (I don´t think this is possible by default, or am I wrong?) you could target their URL scheme and redirect.

To access the old pages (with the new URL) you could then use a "broken link checker" plugin.

**Update:** You could possibly use the hook [described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69369/hook-for-post-and-page-load) to check wether the called post is a post or page and then use `wp_redirect` to call your new URL.

Comment: Is there any way/action hook using which I can do this using php or wp_redirect function in wordpress?